# How to jump out of a Loop and then continue

Tags: php, mysql, loops, conditional-statements

Please i need your help. I'm performing SUM() on a column for course_unit, but i want it to omit a certain condition and then continue the loop. Example: course that have a **grade** of **AR** should be omitted from the loop, then continue.

Thanks for the help and patience. I most appreciate it.
Thanks

**Query4** is used to generate some rows of **course_unit** and **Score**

```
  $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT  c.course_unit, m.score
  FROM    maintable AS m
  INNER JOIN students AS s ON
  m.matric_no = s.matric_no
  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
  m.course_code = c.course_code
  WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
  AND m.level = '".$level."'")
  or die (mysql_error());
```

**Query3** is used for the summation of the **course_units**

```
 $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(c.
 course_unit) AS 'TOTAL'
 FROM    maintable AS m
 INNER JOIN students AS s ON
 m.matric_no = s.matric_no
 INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
 m.course_code = c.course_code
 WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
 AND m.level = '".$level."'")
 or die (mysql_error());
```

**Grades in Respect to Score**

```
    while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
            }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
               $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
               $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
               $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
               $grade = 'E';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 0) &&
            ($row8['score'] < 40){
               $grade = 'F';
            }else{
               $grade = 'AR';
            }   
     }
```

**Calculation of the Grade Point**

```
      $grade_point = 0;
      while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)) {
         if ($row4['score'] >= 70) {
            $score = 5;
          }
          elseif ($row4['score'] >= 60) {
             $score = 4;
          }elseif ($row4['score'] >= 50) {
             $score = 3;
          }elseif ($row4['score'] >= 45) {
             $score = 2;
          }elseif($row4['score'] >= 40) {
             $score = 1;
          }else{
             $score = 0;
          } 

          $grade_point += $score * $row4['course_unit'];

      }
```

**QUESTION UPDATE**

If the loop breaks at

```
$grade == 'AR'
```

Does the course having that **grade** gets it's **course_unit** calculated in 
    SUM() ?

Comment: Use `continue` to jump to the next iteration of a loop, and `break` to exit a loop completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
while( <loop condition> )
{
    if( $grade == "AR" )
    {
        continue;
    }
    <other statements>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this condition be contained in your SQL?

Otherwise,

```
while (something)
{
 if (!omitCondition)
  DoTheThing
}
```

Comment: Which condition are you talking about Sir?